# android embed newline in a notification

Tags: android, notifications

I need to embed a newline in a notification.  I have two lines of data that are different and I need to embed a newline to distinguish between the two.
I trued a backslash-n, but that does not work.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you are getting in new line? Have you tested it some other devices?

Comment: Another option you may try is: String lSep = System.getProperty("line.separator"); use lSep instead of \n.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to do this other than creating a custom `Notification` layout. The `Notification` documentation has a step-by-step process on doing this and is quite thorough. [Here is the link to that.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CustomExpandedView)

Creating the two lines as you require would just mean putting in an extra `TextView` in the layout XML. Then you would just set each `TextView`'s text to your two lines of data, as the example shows.

Answer (score 9):

You do not need to use RemoteViews or a custom layout to show multiple lines, despite what others have said here!
Multiline texts are possible, but only when the notification is expanded.

To do this, you can use [NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle.html). And if you read the dev guides [here](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded) then you'll notice that they mention this tip:

> Tip: To add formatting in your text (bold, italic, line breaks, and so on), you can [add styling with HTML markup](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StylingWithHTML).

So, in other words:

```
val title = "My Title"
val body = "Line 1<br>Line 2<br><i>Italic Line 3</i>"
val formattedBody = SpannableString(
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N) Html.fromHtml(body)
   else Html.fromHtml(body, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
)

NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
   .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary))
   .setContentTitle(title)
   .setContentText(formattedBody)
   .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(formattedBody).setBigContentTitle(title))
   .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_small_notification_icon)
   .build()
```

Things to note about how this works:

1. The title can have *no* formatting (i.e. don't try to use HTML here)
2. The body can have as much formatting as we want, but we must note that the line breaks won’t display when the notification is collapsed. All other HTML formatting works fine in both collapsed/expanded states. You can bold, italicize, etc. as much as you want (I think)

If you don't want to send HTML formatting in your push notification, then another option is to use markdown formatting of some sort and manually handle this before your notification building by using [SpannableStringBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder)

Comment: Line breaks don't work. Have used <br> running on Android 11. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make custom notification builder in your app. more detail here : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CustomExpandedView, It takes me so long to find out the way to make firebase to call onMessageReceived in all cases.

1. app in foreground
2. app in background
3. app was killed.

basically your message to firebase via api must not have "**notification**" key in your json request to firebase server and only use "**data**" key as show below, firebase service will call your onMessageReceived in all cases listed above.

```
{
  "to": "/topics/your_topic",
   "data": {
       "key1":"data_key1",
       "title":"",
       "line1":"data1",
       "line2":"data2"
   }
}
```