# Android multiline notification when collapsed

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-appcompat, androidx

I want to achieve the following functionality with notifications in android:

When the notification is **collapsed**

[image]

When the notification is **expanded**

[image]

I tried doing it with [Notification.InboxStyle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.InboxStyle) and [Notification.BigTextStyle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.BigTextStyle).

But in both of them, I get a multiline text when it's only expanded. Without expanded `\n` is being replaced by `space`. How to achieve multiline text when it's not expanded?

Or it's custom layout notification?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.MessagingStyle is the answer to achieve this effect.

Comment: have you tried System.getProperty("line.separator") instead of \n?

Comment: Yes, but it's not working when the notification is collapsed.

Comment: Please check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/9388369/2110064

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using remote view layouts.

```
val notificationLayout = RemoteViews(packageName, R.layout.notification_small)
NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_notification_overlay)
            .setContentTitle("Multiline Notification")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setCustomContentView(notificationLayout)
```

Here is my custom layout file (notification_small.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test 1 \n Test2  \n Test 3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the MessagingStyle. For example:

```
 public static void notify(final Context context, List<Message> newMessages) {
    Person person = new Person.Builder().setName("Name").build(); // You can also set Person's icon here
    NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle messageStyle = new NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle(person);
    for(Message message : newMessages){
        messageStyle.addMessage(message.text, message.time.getTime(), person);
    }

    String notificationTitle = newMessages.size() + " new messages";
    messageStyle.setConversationTitle(notificationTitle); // Then add the style to the notification builder.
```